# How to use Clipboard API to write image to clipboard in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit, clipboard

The following code (adapted from [here](https://web.dev/async-clipboard/)) successfully writes an image file to the clipboard upon a button click in Chrome:

```
document.getElementById('copy-button').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  try {
    const data = await fetch('image.png')
    const blob = await data.blob()
    await navigator.clipboard.write(
      [new ClipboardItem({[blob.type]: blob})]
    )
    console.log('success')
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`${err.name}:  ${err.message}`)
  }
})
```

(Similar code also works with chaining the promises with `.then()` or copying the contents of a `<canvas>` using `.toBlob()` with a callback function)

However, this fails in Safari, throwing a NotAllowedError. I suspect this is something to do with the asynchronous making of the blob causing Safari think that the call to `write()` is 'outside the scope of a user gesture (such as "click" or "touch" event handlers)' as described [here](https://webkit.org/blog/10855/async-clipboard-api/), since control is released from the event handler during the `await` portions.

For example, the following code pre-loads the blob into a global variable when the script first runs, and the call to `write()` does not need to wait for any other async code to finish executing:

```
let imageBlob
(async function () {
  const data = await fetch('image.png')
  const blob = await data.blob()
  imageBlob = blob
  console.log('Image loaded into memory')
})()

document.getElementById('image-button-preload').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const clipItem = new ClipboardItem({[imageBlob.type]: imageBlob})
  navigator.clipboard.write([clipItem]).then( () => {
    console.log('success')
  }, (reason) => {
    console.log(reason)
  })
})
```

But this is clearly not ideal, especially if the image data is something dynamically created (e.g. in a canvas).

So, the question: **How can I generate an image blob and write this to the clipboard upon a user action which Safari/webkit will accept?** (Or, is this a bug in Safari/webkit's implementation of the API)

Answer (score 2):

The solution (for safari) is to assign a `Promise` to the value of the hashmap you pass into `ClipboardItem` like this:

```
document.getElementById('copy-button').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  try {
    const makeImagePromise = async () => {
      const data = await fetch('image.png')
      return await data.blob()
    }
    await navigator.clipboard.write(
      [new ClipboardItem({[blob.type]: makeImagePromise() })]
    )
    console.log('success')
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`${err.name}:  ${err.message}`)
  }
})
```

That way you're calling `clipboard.write` without awaiting, and Safari will await the promise for you that generates the image.

Note: Other browsers may not support passing a promise to `ClipboardItem`, so you'll likely want to check if the UserAgent contains `Mac` or `iOS` in it before doing this.